# C# Hide Form but stay active

Tags: c#, winforms

I am running a console app that launches a Form, which I want to hide, but stays active so that what it does(launch a .exe on keypress) continues to work.

here is my code that does not work:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Show();
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (f.Name == "Form1") 
        f.Hide();       
        //f.visible = false;
}
```

and tried to set hide or visible on Form_load didn't work either...

any ideas ?

Comment: Show the workflow how did you call this from a console.

Comment: @David, what do you mean ?

Comment: Why do you need a form at all? Why not use a [global keyboard hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook)?

Comment: Why are you searching `OpenForms` when you have a reference to the form right in the variable `f1`?  Note if you're using `OpenForms` there's a 99.9% chance that you're using it incorrectly.  In my entire life I've only ever seen one instance of it being used appropriately.

Comment: it was simple the way I did it, I just need to hide the form but keep it working...

Comment: @Servy I tried it because nothig works... I posted it to give a idea of what I'm trying o do, I know its not good... That's the problem

Comment: @DrewSalesse If the form isn't ever meant to be shown then it's not really a form, conceptually, and as a general rule when programming violating the conceptual purpose of classes tends to cause more problems then it solves.  This entire question is a demonstration of that.

Comment: @Servy [I agree with this](http://preview.images.memegenerator.net/Instance/Preview?imageID=2485&generatorTypeID=&panels=&text0=I%20don't%20always%20agree%20with%20servy&text1=but%20when%20i%20do,%20it's%20about%20using%20classes%20for%20what%20they%20are%20designed%20for&text2=&text3=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this did it, hides form well and stays active.

this.WindowState=FormWindowState.Minimized; 
this.ShowInTaskbar = false

Comment: That doesn't really hide it though.  It minimizes to just above the task bar now.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to use `WinForms` incorrectly. It is not a [golden hammer](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/golden-hammer).

> This AntiPattern results in the misapplication of a favored tool or concept. Developers and managers are comfortable with an existing approach and unwilling to learn and apply one that is better suited.

[image: Golden Hammer]

`WinForms` is not designed to receive keyboard input when the windows are not active (for good reason in my opinion).

What you should look into is a [`Global Keyboard Hook`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook).

Comment: @DrewSalesse I dont see how that code is working as the [`Application.Exit documentation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit(v=vs.71).aspx) says `Form.Closed and Form.Closing events are not raised when the Application.Exit method is called to exit your application.` Even if there is an answer that can hack together what you want, my answer still holds. You are trying to do something that is not what `WinForms` is made for. If you feel the need to add and accept your own answer when you get enough rep, that is your right, but I respectfully disagree.

Comment: You are right... actualy, this does what I want(and I am using the keyboard hook) thanks... this.WindowState=FormWindowState.Minimized; this.ShowInTaskbar = false